# Possibilities of running a custom XMPP server on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp

I've been using GAE XMPP however and have tried working with external XMPP server like OpenFire.

However, what are the possibilities of running a XMPP Server module inside of GAE, something that works around the limitation of opening sockets and threads.

I'm trying to search the web but can't find any information if this was ever been done before in the App Engine platform. I know GAE XMPP API is cool, but there is a requirement that I need not to use that API, but still bound to use GAE platform. Much like we don't use the UserService API of GAE.

Comment: Have you read the 1.7.2. blogpost and this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dF9QR3pnQ2pNa0dqalViSTZoenVkcHc6MQ#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run one on [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine).  However, at this time there is no support for running an XMPP service on App Engine itself.